# Aligning Divs With Text and Images, for Desktop and Mobile. While preserving mouse over effect

Tags: css, html, mobile, desktop

I am struggling to get divs with both images and text to line up horizontally properly. With out the text. Everything works as it should. But the moment I add text to things everything breaks. Suggestions are welcome and appreciated. I apologize if my formatting of this post is improper. Relatively new here.

HTML:

```
    <div id="icon-container">
    <div id="icon"><img class="hover-icon1" 
    src="/Portals/0/Images/NewSite/comp.png?ver=2017-05-26-102442-467"/>
    </br>
    <h4 class="icon-text">Content here</h4>
    </div>
    <div id="icon"><img class="hover-icon2" 
    src="/Portals/0/Images/NewSite/phone.png?ver=2017-05-26-102445-013"/>
    </br>
    <h4 class="icon-text">Content here</h4>
    </div>
    <div id="icon"><img class="hover-icon3" 
    src="/Portals/0/Images/NewSite/email.png?ver=2017-05-26-102444-373"/>
    </br>
    <h4 class="icon-text">Content here</h4>
    </div>
    <div id="icon"><img class="hover-icon4" 
    src="/Portals/0/Images/NewSite/alert.png?ver=2017-05-26-102443-217"/>
    </br>
    <h4 class="icon-text">Content here</h4>
    </div>
    <div id="icon"><img class="hover-icon5" 
    src="/Portals/0/Images/NewSite/backup.png?ver=2017-05-26-102443-747"/>
    </br>
    <h4 class="icon-text">Content here</h4>
    </div>
    <div id="icon"><img class="hover-icon6" 
    src="/Portals/0/Images/NewSite/web.png?ver=2017-05-26-102445-577"/>
    </br>
    <h4 class="icon-text">Content here</h4>
    </div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
    /* CSS For Icons */

    #icon-container {
    width:100%;
    }

    #icon {
    width:16.66%;
    height: 200px;
    display:inline-block;
    margin-right: -4px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 1%;
    text-align: center;
    }




    @media all and (max-width:800px) 
   {
   #icon
   {
   display: table;
   margin: 0 auto;
   height: 100px;
   text-align: center;
   }
  }

   img.hover-icon1, img.hover-icon2, img.hover-icon3, img.hover-icon4, 
   img.hover-icon5, img.hover-icon6 {
   margin:20px;
   padding:3px;
   float:left;
   -webkit-transition: margin 0.5s ease-out;
   -moz-transition: margin 0.5s ease-out;
   -o-transition: margin 0.5s ease-out;
   -moz-border-radius: 70px; 
   -webkit-border-radius: 70px; 
   border-radius: 70px;
   background-color: #1356d1
   }

   img.hover-icon1:hover, img.hover-icon2:hover, img.hover-icon3:hover, 
   img.hover-icon4:hover, img.hover-icon5:hover, img.hover-icon6:hover {
   cursor:pointer;
   margin-top: 5px;
   }

   h4.icon-text {

   clear: left;
   display: block;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add float left to `#icon`

```css
    /* CSS For Icons */

    #icon-container {
    width:100%;
    }

    #icon {
    width:16.66%;
    height: 200px;
    display:inline-block;
    margin-right: -4px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 1%;
    text-align: center;
    float: left;
    }




    @media all and (max-width:800px) 
   {
   #icon
   {
   display: table;
   margin: 0 auto;
   height: 100px;
   text-align: center;
   }
  }

   img.hover-icon1, img.hover-icon2, img.hover-icon3, img.hover-icon4, 
   img.hover-icon5, img.hover-icon6 {
   margin:20px;
   padding:3px;
   float:left;
   -webkit-transition: margin 0.5s ease-out;
   -moz-transition: margin 0.5s ease-out;
   -o-transition: margin 0.5s ease-out;
   -moz-border-radius: 70px; 
   -webkit-border-radius: 70px; 
   border-radius: 70px;
   background-color: #1356d1
   }

   img.hover-icon1:hover, img.hover-icon2:hover, img.hover-icon3:hover, 
   img.hover-icon4:hover, img.hover-icon5:hover, img.hover-icon6:hover {
   cursor:pointer;
   margin-top: 5px;
   }

   h4.icon-text {

   clear: left;
   display: block;
   }
```

```html
    <div id="icon-container">
    <div id="icon"><img class="hover-icon1" 
    src="/Portals/0/Images/NewSite/comp.png?ver=2017-05-26-102442-467"/>
    </br>
    <h4 class="icon-text">Content here</h4>
    </div>
    <div id="icon"><img class="hover-icon2" 
    src="/Portals/0/Images/NewSite/phone.png?ver=2017-05-26-102445-013"/>
    </br>
    <h4 class="icon-text">Content here</h4>
    </div>
    <div id="icon"><img class="hover-icon3" 
    src="/Portals/0/Images/NewSite/email.png?ver=2017-05-26-102444-373"/>
    </br>
    <h4 class="icon-text">Content here</h4>
    </div>
    <div id="icon"><img class="hover-icon4" 
    src="/Portals/0/Images/NewSite/alert.png?ver=2017-05-26-102443-217"/>
    </br>
    <h4 class="icon-text">Content here</h4>
    </div>
    <div id="icon"><img class="hover-icon5" 
    src="/Portals/0/Images/NewSite/backup.png?ver=2017-05-26-102443-747"/>
    </br>
    <h4 class="icon-text">Content here</h4>
    </div>
    <div id="icon"><img class="hover-icon6" 
    src="/Portals/0/Images/NewSite/web.png?ver=2017-05-26-102445-577"/>
    </br>
    <h4 class="icon-text">Content here</h4>
    </div>
    </div>
```